# Prove a ray inside compact convex set will always hit the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact convex set in Normed linear space.Prove given two distinct point $x,y \in K$,the ray $\{x + t(y-x)\mid t>0\}$ will always hit the boundary point of $K$.

I can formalize this question as follows:

$\sup\{t\mid z = x+t(y-x)\in K,t>0\}<\infty$ and the sup is attainable at some $z\in \partial K$

I have a not very good proof,is there some good proof for this proposition?

I do as follows,if sup is unbounded there exist a sequence of $t\to \infty$,by convexity,which means ray contains in the bounded set,which is impossible.(due to the fact that subset of bounded set is still bounded,and ray is unbounded in normed linear space(I don't know how to show unbounded of ray exactly at topological vector space)).

Now there exist a sequence that approximate the sup,since closeness of K,the limit point also lies in K.(as follows since $t_n \to t^*$ we have $\|t_n-t^*\|\|y-x\| \to 0$ which means $z_n\to x+t^*(y-x)$)

The limit for TVS is proved as follows:$z = x +t^*(y-x)$ since any neiborhood around this point is abosrbing,which means at direction $y-x$ exist a small $\epsilon$ segment lies inside it.that is exist $x + (t^*-\epsilon)(y-x)$ contains inside neiborhood,since $t_n\to t^*$ hence must exist some $z_n$ lies in this neiborhood.

Comment: Compact in topological linear space should suffice - or do you want to also show that the boundary point is unique?

Comment: Your approach looks solid. If you let $t^*$ be the supremum you've constructed, then $x + t^*(y - x)$ will lie in $K$ (as $K$ is closed), but will also lie in $\partial K$, since $x + (t^* + 1/n)(y - x) \notin K$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, and they converge to $x + t^*(y - n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set
$$T = \{t \ | \ x + t(y-x) \in K \}$$
Since $K$ is bounded, $T$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $K$ is closed, $T$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $1\in T$. Consider $t^{*} = \sup T$. Clearly $t^{*}\in T$.  Moreover for every $t > t^{*}$, we have $x + (t^{*}+\frac{1}{n}) (y-x) \not \in K$ and $x + (t^{*}+\frac{1}{n}) (y-x) \to x + t^{*} (y-x)$. Therefore $x + t^{*} (y-x) \in \partial K$

Note: We did not use $K$ convex. If $K$ is moreover convex, $T$ is a closed segment containing $[0,1]$. The points on the boundary of $T$ are in $\partial K$.

$\bf{Added:}$ The only condition needed is $K$ bounded.  Since the we have the partition of the full space
$$X = \mathring{K}\cup \partial K \cup \mathring  {X\backslash K}$$

If the ray $\{ x + t (y-x) \ | t>0\}$ did not intersect the boundary, it would be contained in $\mathring{K}$, since $(0, \infty)$ is connected, contradiction with $K$ bounded.

Comment: There is another irrelevant question,boundness in Topologial vector space is defined for any neighborhood at origin,can we move it to any fixed point intead of origin?

Comment: @yi_li:  Yes, the translate of a bounded set is bounded.  Note that the map $t \mapsto x + t(y-x)$ is continuous, works for tvs.  In normed spaces,  In fact, is is an embedding ($y\ne x$ assumed of course). IF $K$ is convex, the set $T$ is automatically convex, no topology required.